# Word count from a file in C

Tags: c, count

I did an assignment which did not get me quite the result I was expecting and failing in a particular use case. I gave the problem as well as the code below. Can someone help me with the bug?

This is the assignment:

> Write a function named `countString` that takes a string value as input from the user, and counts the number of occurrences of the given input string in a file named **notes.txt**, and returns the count.
> The function should return 0, if the input string doesn't exist in the file content.
>
> Note: The length of input string will not exceed 15 characters.
>
> Sample Input: `Hello`
> Output: `2`

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int countString()
{
    char str1[16];
    char str2[16];
    char *str;
    int strCount = 0;

    //get user input for the string he wants to search and count
    str = fgets(str1, 16, stdin);
    
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("notes.txt", "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        puts("\nCannot open any such file");
        return 0;
    }
    
    /* subtle bug is that the last word is not getting counted if 
       the file is saved on the same line as the word instead of a
       new line
       example problem: notes.txt contains: two words "shut"
       shut shut and file is saved after the second 't' in the 
       second shut, this shut is not being Counted.
     */
    
    while (fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), fp1) != NULL)
    {
        fputs(str2, stdout);
        if (strcmp(str, str2) == 0)
            strCount++;
    }

    fclose(fp1);
    return strCount;
}

int main()
{
    printf("\n%d", countString());
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now seems like a very good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: As a hint, what does the `fgets` function really do? Does it really read *words*? And why are you using `strcmp` to compare the input from the file with the filename?

Comment: If the input word is the maximum length 15 then the `fgets()` call will not retain the newline. For all shorter input words it will, so you'll have to do something about that.

Comment: If you don't know that each word in the file is at most 15 characters and starts on a new line, then your program logic is wrong. If it is to find words in an arbitrary file of text, then you need to cater for instances where the word starts part way into your buffer, and may extend beyond.

Comment: Is the test file a word list (one word per line) or an actual sentence as described? If the latter, there is no "subtle bug" –  the code makes no attempt to separate the file content into words. You'd be better off using `fscanf(fp1, "%s", ...);`. Note too that the spec says nothing about the word length in the file. It's never a good idea to be mean with buffer sizes: you don't have to pay for them.

Comment: I don't even know why you are not including `curses.h` to use `getch()` in your code.

Comment: ... or `conio.h` on MS VC.

Comment: "Cannot open any such file" is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Which file?  Why can the file not be opened?  Use `const char *name = "notes.txt"; if ( (ifp = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL) { perror(name); ...}`  It explains why the fopen failed and writes the error message to the proper stream.

Comment: @WilliamPursell  A failed `fopen()` does not certainly set `errno` per the standard C library, reducing `perror(name)` usefulness as there is no explanation.  Perhaps you are relying on some implementation specific behavior?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Although the C standard does not specify that `fopen` sets `errno`, every major platform that a student is likely to encounter will set it and `perror` will give a useful error message.  And, frankly, even "notes.txt: not a typewriter" is a more useful error message than "Cannot open any such file".  Also, it's on the right stream.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:

- `char str1[16];` is technically not large enough to read a line with a 15 character string: the newline will not be read if the string has 15 or more characters. This is not a problem per se, but it would be more consistent to make the buffer larger and always strip the trailing newline.
- you read strings from the file with `fgets` with a short 16 byte buffer.  This will truncate longer lines in blocks of 15 characters, some of which may match the string in `str1`, only if this one has 15 characters, or the last portion of longer lines lines that have a trailing newline if the string in `str1` is shorter than 15 characters and included a newline.  Many potential matches will be missed (as in your example).

You should use a different method to read the string and to parse the file:

- You should read the string in a longer buffer and strip the trailing newline.
- You could read the file contents using a larger buffer and use `strstr` to try and locate occurrences of the string in the line, handling potentially more than one match per line.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int countString(void)
{
    char str[32];
    char line[256];
    int strCount = 0;

    //get user input for the string he wants to search and count
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        // could return -1 to indicate an error
        return 0;
    }
    int len = strlen(str);
    if (len > 0 && str[len - 1] == '\n')
       str[--len] = '\0';
    if (len == 0) {
        // could return -1 to indicate an error
        return 0;
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen("notes.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n",
                "notes.txt", strerror(errno)))
        // could return -1 to indicate an error
        return 0;
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
        for (char *s = line; (s = strstr(s, str)) != NULL; s++) {
            strCount++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return strCount;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", countString());
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

There are 2 remaining issues in the above code for you to study and fix if needed:

- if the string is empty, `countString` returns `0`, whether empty strings should be considered absent or present in the file is a matter of specification, which the problem statement does not define.
- if the file has lines longer than 255 characters, `countString` may miss occurrences of the string that span boundaries of 255 character blocks on such lines.  This can be addressed by copying the end of long lines to the beginning of the buffer and reading the remainder of the line after the copy, I shall leave it as an exercise.
- `countString` does not count overlapping matches such as `aba` in `ababa`. Should these matches count for `2` or just `1` is also a matter of specification. The problem statement seems to indicate the expected answer is `2`, but it should be more precise as this interpretation is not necessarily the most common one.  The above code will return `2`, how would you modify it to return `1` instead?

Comment: Good use of `strstr()` rather than `strcmp()`.